# Stored procedures and their output

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Client that calls a stored procedure can handle only recordset output only.

However store procedure is supposed to return simple 0 or 1 value as a result of several internal queries.

Is there any work around I could have a store procedure variable value returned as a kind a recordset?

Comment: Look here for clear examples of returning recordsets in Oracle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305883/toad-displaying-cursor-recordset-returned-by-stored-procedure/14320426#14320426

Answer (score 1):

Return a cursor variable; open the cursor variable with a SELECT .. FROM DUAL of the values you want to return from the procedure.

The procedure will return a cursor returning a single row containing those values.

Answer (score 1):

From your PROCEDURE do

```
OPEN resultsCursor_ FOR
Select 1 As aValue FROM DUAL;
```

OR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetAValue
(
  results_       OUT     SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
    MY_COUNT_  INT;
BEGIN 

    MY_COUNT_ := 10;

    OPEN results_ FOR
    SELECT MY_COUNT_ AS MyCount FROM DUAL;

END GetAValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

A procedure cannot return a value; you need a function to do this.

If you really want a procedure to "give" a cursor back to the caller, you can
use something like this:

```
 --Declare this type in a package X
 --The caller must have access to the package X.
 TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
 CREATE OR REPLACE
 PROCEDURE test (
                   p_param1           IN  VARCHAR2,
                   p_cur              OUT X.REF_CURSOR,
                   p_error_code       OUT NUMBER,
                   p_error_message    OUT VARCHAR2
                 )
 AS
 BEGIN
      OPEN p_cur FOR
        SELECT * FROM TABLE;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN

     p_error_code := SQLCODE;
     p_error_message := SQLERRM;

 END;
```

If there is no error set, the caller can then execute this cursor and fetch rows against it.

Comment: After so many attempts still no luck. Maybe you could point out, where it goes wrong, please.

Comment: where it goes wrong,please?

spec:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CTI_MATRIX.AMD AS
  TYPE REF_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
  PROCEDURE AMD_NEEDMSG (v_CRN IN VARCHAR2, return_recordset OUT REF_CURSOR);
END AMD;

body:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CTI_MATRIX.AMD AS
PROCEDURE AMD_NEEDMSG (v_CRN IN VARCHAR2, return_recordset OUT REF_CURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
    -- 
END AMD_NEEDMSG;
END AMD;

Failing block from TOAD:
DECLARE 
  RETURN_RECORDSET AMD.REF_CURSOR;
BEGIN 
  RETURN_RECORDSET := NULL;
  CTI_MATRIX.AMD.AMD_NEEDMSG ( '123456789', RETURN_RECORDSET );
END;
Error: PLS-00382 Expression is of wrong type line 5

Comment: Yes; which line is resulting in an error?  I have been using this example in 11G.  If you can post the code, I can test it out here.  Thanks

Comment: I am using following instead:
  OPEN p_cur FOR 
    SELECT return_flag AS ReturnFLag FROM DUAL;

And can't work put how to access this record set from outside using something like:

DECLARE 
  RETURN_RECORDSET CTI_MATRIX.AMD.REF_CURSOR;

BEGIN 
  V_CRN := '5457648547567';

  CTI_MATRIX.AMD_NEEDMSG ( V_CRN, RETURN_RECORDSET);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('');

  COMMIT; 
END;

What needs to go inside to access field ReturnFlag and it content from DUAL table? Tried all sort of things but to no avail! Thanks